# Where is yield defined in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, implementation, yield

I wanted to look at the implementation of `yield` in Rails. I've tried [searching the codebase on Github](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3arails/rails%20%22def%20yield%22&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=) for "def yield" with no luck. I've also had no luck [searching api.rubyonrails.org on Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3aapi.rubyonrails.org%20yield&oq=site%3aapi.rubyonrails.org%20yield&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=12&gs_upl=0l0l0l12450l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&gs_l=serp.12...0l0l0l12451l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0). It's not defined in the [CaptureHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html) along with related methods `content_for` and `provide`.

Where is `yield` defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`yield` is a Ruby method ([Proc#yield](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html#method-i-yield)) and not something Rails specific.

Comment: Hey Niklas, what do you mean exactly? Just pointed out that it's not a Rails method. Additionally i provided a link to the documentation because he wanted to have a look at the implementation.

(Response to a comment that was deleted.)